# Prestashop - An error occured while sending a message

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.x. I encountered an error while trying sending message from Contact Page form.
At first it shows

> An error occurred while sending the message.

But message is sent to the BO Customer Service at first attempt despite error is displayed.
If I re-send the same message with same email. it succeeds without any errors.

Comment: Can you open Developper Console in Google Chrome or Firefox and watch the response (and the problem) in Network Tab ?

Comment: I may not have got that. If I am correct, this is what I did. https://imgur.com/IGmnXwG. Now what should I look for?

Comment: Open the developper tab, when you click on send button, a new request will be displayed, just click on the raw and observe the response provided.